# joda:format returns empty string

Tags: java, datetime, format, jodatime, jspx

I'm using joda:format to format my DataTime object in jspx, but it doesn't look like the tag does anything at all.

At the header of the page, I have this:

```
<jsp:root xmlns:joda="http://www.joda.org/joda/time/tags">
```

The field:

```
<div><joda:format value="${myDateTime}" pattern="MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss" /></div>
```

The markup after the page finished loading looks like this:

```
<div>
  <joda:format value="2013-08-31T02:01:57.939-04:00" pattern="MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss">     
  </joda:format>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `joda-time-jsptags` to your classpath.
If you are using `maven` tool then add this dependency to your web module

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
    <artifactId>joda-time-jsptags</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

or download `jar` from [here](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=joda-time/joda-time-jsptags/1.1.1/joda-time-jsptags-1.1.1.jar) and add to your project manually

Comment: errrr... this is jspx. I don't think <%  %> will do.